# I am trying to run mongod on m1 pro macbook, but getting the following log

Tags: mongodb, apple-m1

I am trying to run mongod on m1 pro macbook, but getting the following log :

[image]

Can anyone give solution for this

Comment: "address already in use" means there is already something listening on port 27017.  Is there a mongod already running?

Comment: when I checked activity monitor it is running in background, but in brew services it is showing as stopped.
And i was able to use mongo and monogoosh commands without any error

Answer (score 0):

Please change the mongodb default port to something like '27030' in the mongod.conf file. Usually you can find this file in this path '/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf.'. Then try to establish the connection. Let me know if you face any issues.